# Pycharm font color change debbug hint

Tags: pycharm

I want to change below the red box text color but I can't find the name of it.

plz teach me what is it called and is it possible to change color in pycharm?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Debugger and select `Inlined values`. You can change the foreground color to any color you'd like.

Comment: @jihyeon Let me know if that's not the category you are looking for. You can play around with the other options. Any debugger related color scheme is defined in `Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Debugger`